# why does tensorboard give this error: InvalidArgumentError: Nan in summary histogram for

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tf.keras, tensorboardx

I built the model to classification using 1D convolution layers using tf.Keras .this works well if I remove the tensorboard.As I'm a beginner,I can't figure it out what the problem is.
Please help

```
%reload_ext tensorboard
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation,Conv1D,MaxPool1D,GlobalAveragePooling1D,Dropout,Flatten,concatenate,Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

inp = Input(shape=(1000,21))
a = Conv1D(filters=250,padding='valid', kernel_size=(8),strides=1)(inp)
a=MaxPool1D(1000-8+1,strides=1,padding='valid')(a)
a=Flatten()(a)
b = Conv1D(filters=250,padding='valid', kernel_size=(12))(inp)
b=MaxPool1D(1000-12+1,strides=1,padding='valid')(b)
b=Flatten()(b)
c = Conv1D(filters=250,padding='valid', kernel_size=(16))(inp)
c=MaxPool1D(1000-16+1,strides=1,padding='valid')(c)
c=Flatten()(c)
d = Conv1D(filters=250,padding='valid', kernel_size=(20))(inp)
d=MaxPool1D(1000-20+1,strides=1,padding='valid')(d)
d=Flatten()(d)
e = Conv1D(filters=250,padding='valid', kernel_size=(24))(inp)
e=MaxPool1D(1000-24+1,strides=1,padding='valid')(e)
e=Flatten()(e)
f = Conv1D(filters=250,padding='valid', kernel_size=(28))(inp)
f=MaxPool1D(1000-28+1,strides=1,padding='valid')(f)
f=Flatten()(f)
g = Conv1D(filters=250,padding='valid', kernel_size=(32))(inp)
g=MaxPool1D(1000-32+1,strides=1,padding='valid')(g)
g=Flatten()(g)
h= Conv1D(filters=250,padding='valid', kernel_size=(36))(inp)
h=MaxPool1D(1000-36+1,strides=1,padding='valid')(h)
h=Flatten()(h)
model=concatenate([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h],1)
model = Dropout(0.3)(model)
#model = Dense(2000,activation='relu')(model)
model = Dense(2892,activation='sigmoid')(model)
model = Model(inp, model)
print(model.summary())
```

and use the sequence class batch generator to input batches

```
class MyGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    'Generates data for Keras'
    def __init__(self, ids, train_dir):
        'Initialization'
        self.ids = ids
        self.train_dir = train_dir


    def __len__(self):
        'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
        batch_size=100
        numofBatchs=math.ceil(len(self.train_dir) / batch_size)
        return numofBatchs

    def __getitem__(self, index):

      test_resL=[]
      test_resD=[]
      start_posT = index * 100
      end_posT = min(start_posT + 100, len(self.train_dir))
      test_resL=self.ids[start_posT:end_posT]
      test_resD=self.train_dir[start_posT:end_posT]
      #iTest += 1

      isize=len(test_resL)


      dataTest = np.zeros( (isize,1000,21), dtype=np.float32 )
      labelsTest = np.zeros( (isize,2892), dtype=np.uint8 )    
      #rawTest = []

      for i , idy in enumerate(test_resL):
          label=idy
          #print(label)        
          encoding_label_np(label, labelsTest[i] )
      for i , idx in enumerate(test_resD):
          seq=idx        
          encoding_seq_np(seq, dataTest[i] )
      #dataShped=np.reshape(dataTest,(-1, 1, 1000, 21))
      # print(dataTest[0:2])
      # print(labelsTest[0:2])                
      return dataTest,labelsTest
```

after adding tensor board it runs 1st epoch only.

```
poch 1/20
10431/10431 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.7652 - accuracy: 0.3496
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
_FallbackException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_summary_ops.py in write_histogram_summary(writer, step, tag, values, name)
    463         _ctx._context_handle, tld.device_name, "WriteHistogramSummary", name,
--> 464         tld.op_callbacks, writer, step, tag, values)
    465       return _result

_FallbackException: This function does not handle the case of the path where all inputs are not already EagerTensors.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
13 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     62     if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError: Nan in summary histogram for: conv1d_16/kernel_0 [Op:WriteHistogramSummary]
```

Comment: Is your issue resolved now ? Else, Can you share reproducible code to replicate your problem. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. I found it. The problem was the sigmoid activation and I changed it to softmax. After that It worked well.

Comment: That's good to hear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing the solution here (Answer Section), even though it is present in the comment section for the benefit of the community.

```
InvalidArgumentError: Nan in summary histogram for: conv1d_16/kernel_0 [Op:WriteHistogramSummary]
```

This issue was resolved after modifying activation function from `sigmoid` to `softmax` in  the dense layer of Model.

Final Model Structure is as below

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation,Conv1D,MaxPool1D,GlobalAveragePooling1D,Dropout,Flatten,concatenate,Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

inp = Input(shape=(1000,21))
a = Conv1D(filters=250,padding='valid', kernel_size=(8),strides=1)(inp)
a=MaxPool1D(1000-8+1,strides=1,padding='valid')(a)
a=Flatten()(a)
b = Conv1D(filters=250,padding='valid', kernel_size=(12))(inp)
b=MaxPool1D(1000-12+1,strides=1,padding='valid')(b)
b=Flatten()(b)
c = Conv1D(filters=250,padding='valid', kernel_size=(16))(inp)
c=MaxPool1D(1000-16+1,strides=1,padding='valid')(c)
c=Flatten()(c)
d = Conv1D(filters=250,padding='valid', kernel_size=(20))(inp)
d=MaxPool1D(1000-20+1,strides=1,padding='valid')(d)
d=Flatten()(d)
e = Conv1D(filters=250,padding='valid', kernel_size=(24))(inp)
e=MaxPool1D(1000-24+1,strides=1,padding='valid')(e)
e=Flatten()(e)
f = Conv1D(filters=250,padding='valid', kernel_size=(28))(inp)
f=MaxPool1D(1000-28+1,strides=1,padding='valid')(f)
f=Flatten()(f)
g = Conv1D(filters=250,padding='valid', kernel_size=(32))(inp)
g=MaxPool1D(1000-32+1,strides=1,padding='valid')(g)
g=Flatten()(g)
h= Conv1D(filters=250,padding='valid', kernel_size=(36))(inp)
h=MaxPool1D(1000-36+1,strides=1,padding='valid')(h)
h=Flatten()(h)
model=concatenate([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h],1)
model = Dropout(0.3)(model)
#model = Dense(2000,activation='relu')(model)
model = Dense(2892,activation='softmax')(model)
model = Model(inp, model)
print(model.summary())
```

Output:

```
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 1000, 21)]   0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d (Conv1D)                 (None, 993, 250)     42250       input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)               (None, 989, 250)     63250       input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_2 (Conv1D)               (None, 985, 250)     84250       input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_3 (Conv1D)               (None, 981, 250)     105250      input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_4 (Conv1D)               (None, 977, 250)     126250      input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_5 (Conv1D)               (None, 973, 250)     147250      input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_6 (Conv1D)               (None, 969, 250)     168250      input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_7 (Conv1D)               (None, 965, 250)     189250      input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d (MaxPooling1D)    (None, 1, 250)       0           conv1d[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_1 (MaxPooling1D)  (None, 1, 250)       0           conv1d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_2 (MaxPooling1D)  (None, 1, 250)       0           conv1d_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_3 (MaxPooling1D)  (None, 1, 250)       0           conv1d_3[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_4 (MaxPooling1D)  (None, 1, 250)       0           conv1d_4[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_5 (MaxPooling1D)  (None, 1, 250)       0           conv1d_5[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_6 (MaxPooling1D)  (None, 1, 250)       0           conv1d_6[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_7 (MaxPooling1D)  (None, 1, 250)       0           conv1d_7[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)               (None, 250)          0           max_pooling1d[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)             (None, 250)          0           max_pooling1d_1[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_2 (Flatten)             (None, 250)          0           max_pooling1d_2[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_3 (Flatten)             (None, 250)          0           max_pooling1d_3[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_4 (Flatten)             (None, 250)          0           max_pooling1d_4[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_5 (Flatten)             (None, 250)          0           max_pooling1d_5[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_6 (Flatten)             (None, 250)          0           max_pooling1d_6[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_7 (Flatten)             (None, 250)          0           max_pooling1d_7[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate (Concatenate)       (None, 2000)         0           flatten[0][0]                    
                                                                 flatten_1[0][0]                  
                                                                 flatten_2[0][0]                  
                                                                 flatten_3[0][0]                  
                                                                 flatten_4[0][0]                  
                                                                 flatten_5[0][0]                  
                                                                 flatten_6[0][0]                  
                                                                 flatten_7[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)               (None, 2000)         0           concatenate[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                   (None, 2892)         5786892     dropout[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 6,712,892
Trainable params: 6,712,892
Non-trainable params: 0
______________________________________
```